# How to compare my two projectModels objects one is from a local value and the other from a future? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, object, compare

I'm trying to compare two objects and see if they have the same values, one of the object comes from an future api call

```
ProjectModel response = await ProjectServices.fetchSingleProjectStream(
        projectId: projectId,
      );
```

and the other one from a local value which I fill with another api call whom I call **onInit()**

```
final _projectModel = ProjectModel(
    guid: '',
    projectColor: '',
    title: '',
    tags: [],
    tasks: [],
    teamMembers: [],
  ).obs;
```

```
  fetchSingleProject() async {
    try {
      if (_projectModel.value.tasks!.isEmpty) {
        _isLoading(true);
      }
      ProjectModel response = await ProjectServices.fetchSingleProjectStream(
        projectId: projectId,
      );
      print('from local: ${_projectModel.value.tasks![0].description}');
      print('from api: ${response.tasks![0].description}');
      // var shouldReload = projectModel.tasks!
      //     .any((element) => _projectModel.value.tasks!.contains(element));
      // bool shouldReload = response.tasks == _projectModel.value.tasks;
      const DeepCollectionEquality dc = DeepCollectionEquality.unordered();
      bool shouldReload = dc.equals(
        response.tags!.toList(),
        _tagsList.toList(),
      );
      print('should the stream reload: $shouldReload');
      if (shouldReload) {
        _projectModel.value = response;
        _tagsList.assignAll(response.tags!);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Get.snackbar('Opss', 'An error occourred');
    } finally {
      _isLoading(false);
    }
  }

  fetchInitialProject() async {
    try {
      _isLoading(true);
      ProjectModel response = await ProjectServices.fetchSingleProjectStream(
        projectId: projectId,
      );
      _projectModel.value = response;
      _tagsList.assignAll(response.tags!);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Get.snackbar('Error', '$e');
    } finally {
      _isLoading(false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    if (_projectModel.value.tasks!.isEmpty) await fetchInitialProject();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onReady() {
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 3), (timer) async {
      await fetchSingleProject();
    });
    super.onReady();
  }
```

And when I print the values of each of the object they come out the same but the result comes out false why is that and how do I fix it?

```
      print('from local: ${_projectModel.value.tasks![0].description}');
      print('from api: ${response.tasks![0].description}');
---
flutter: from local: This is an autogenerated #tbd, @ShemsedinRaketa
flutter: from api: This is an autogenerated #tbd, @ShemsedinRaketa
---
```

Method 1 of trying to compare the **tasksList**:

```
bool shouldReload = response.tasks == _projectModel.value.tasks;

// returns false
```

Method 2 of trying to compare the **tasksList**:

```
// importing form the collection package
      const DeepCollectionEquality dc = DeepCollectionEquality.unordered();
      bool shouldReload = dc.equals(
        response.tags!.toList(),
        _tagsList.toList(),
      );
// returns false as well
```

Method 3 of tryingto compare the **tasksList**:

```
      var shouldReload = projectModel.tasks!
          .any((element) => _projectModel.value.tasks!.contains(element));
// even if all the values are not the same it still returns true when 
// only one of the values matches
// flutter: from local: This is an autogenerated #tbd,
// @ShemsedinRaketa
// flutter: from api: This is an autogenerated #tbd, @ShemsedinRaketa poakdhmnbs
// flutter: should the stream reload: true
```

What I want to achieve with this is a stream which I want to be able to control when to load the new data which comes from the api and when not, which is when the data that comes from the api is the same as those in the local then don't update the UI.

Comment: So do you want to check if **every single value** of `projectModel` and `response` are the same? Or just if their `tasks` list is the same?

Comment: @EimantasG well if possible the first but the second would work as well

Comment: Can you then print `_projectModel.value.tasks` and `response.tasks`, so I can see how they look?

Comment: it just returns ```flutter: from local: [Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel']
flutter: from api: [Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel', Instance of 'TasksModel']```

Comment: And how does `TasksModel` Object looks like?

Comment: ```class TasksModel {
  String? guid;
  String? description;
  bool? closed;
  int? taskId;
  int? orderId;
  String? projectProjectCode;
  String? taskNumber;
  String? createdByName;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? projectGuid;
  int? kanbanOrderId;
  bool? pinned;
  List? files;```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245110/discussion-between-niitii-and-eimantas-g).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
bool areEqual(List<Person> a, List<Person> b){
  for(int i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(a[i].id != b[i].id){
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

void main(){
List<Person> a = [Person(),Person()];
List<Person> b = [Person(),Person()];
}
```

This is how your function could look like, but change it to your Objects
not Person and value is not id, but description for you